# schema.methods vs schema.statics

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have model(auth.model.js) like below

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 255,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 1024,
    },
})
   // this one I'm accessing outside of the file and it is not returning any value
    User.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            email: this.email
        }, 'jwtPrivateKey');
        return token;
    }
    // this one I'm accessing outside of the file and it is returning value
    User.static.generateAuthToken = function (a) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            email: this.email
        }, 'jwtPrivateKey');
        return token;
    }

exports.User = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

to get the token in `auth.controler.js` I'm trying to accessing like below

```
const {
    User,generateAuthToken
} = require('../models/user.model');
```

and it has for the static method

```
const token = User.generateAuthToken(req.body.email);
```

for schema.methods

```
const token = User.generateAuthToken();
```

when I try to accessing the static method it is working fine, where as when I try to accessing the schema.method it is not returning any thing.

why it is not working `schema.method`. could any please let me know the reason or any thing wrong implementation in  my code

Comment: The difference of `method` vs `static` is that `User.generateAuthToken()` is the **static** method, much like a `static` on a class definition in various other languages or even ES6 classes. The **method** would be invoked from an **instance** of the "class". i.e `let user = new User(); let token = user.generateAuthToken();` As such the **method** has access to the **current instance data**. A **static** on the other hand **does not**. Therefore the the `this` in a `static` does not see `this.email` as an existing value.